# JQuery AJAX how to convert HTML form data to JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, api, post

I am working on a tutorial and would like to post data to an api.  i am looking at this swagger doc http://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/addPet I would like to take HTML form data and post it to an API.  The API requires that the JSON be made and to a format like this:

```
{
  "id": 1104,
  "category": {
     "id": 0,
     "name": "string"
},
"name": "doggie",
"photoUrls": [
    "string"
],
"tags": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string"
  }
],
"status": "available"
}
```

how would I configure the form data to meet these specifications?
here is what i currently have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>

   <form id="form" action="" method="post">
    Id: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
    Category Id: <input type="text" name="categoryId"><br>
    Category Name: <input type="text" name="categoryName"><br>
    PhotoURLs: <input type="text" name="photoUrls"><br>
    TagsId: <input type="text" name="tagsId"><br>
    TagsName: <input type="text" name="tagsName"><br>
    Status: <input type="text" name="status"><br>
    <input id="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>




<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // click on button submit
        $("#submit").on('click', function(){

       var formData = {
            "id": $('input[name=id]').val(),
            "category": {
                "id": $('input[name=categoryId]').val(),
                "name": $('input[name=categoryName]').val()
            },
            "name": $('input[name=name]').val(),
            "photoUrls": [
                $('input[name=photoUrls]').val()
            ],
            "tags": [
                {
                    "id": $('input[name=tagsId]').val(),
                    "name": $('input[name=tagsName]').val()
                }
            ],
            "status": $('input[name=status]').val()
        };

           // send ajax
           $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: 'https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet', // url where to submit the request
            type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
            dataType : 'json', // data type
            data : JSON.stringify(formData), // post data || get data
            success : function(result) {
                // you can see the result from the console
                // tab of the developer tools
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
            }
        })
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: figured it out i had to add a headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },

Comment: You can add a `contentType` parameter to your `$.ajax` call directly, you don't have to use `headers`. Also, it's better when you write the whole thing as an answer below and roll back your question to its original state. You can then properly close the thread by marking your own answer as accepted and the thread gets the question-answer layout that is more useful for future readers.